# Lua unexpected identifier issue in VSC

Tags: lua, syntax-error

i was transfering code from my tablet's ide to VSC to tweak it and continue it on PC but i've ran into an issue. I'm trying to define a variable by using `local xyz = 0` but it keeps returning `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` when i try to run it but it worked perfectly fine on my mobile IDE. (on pc i'm using Visual Studio Code with the Lua extension by sumneko and on pc i was using an app called TouchLua+)[debug console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ms6.png)

i've tried looking it up on google but there were no posts describing any similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without more code or context(not familiar with the touchapp) but this as a standalone piece of lua is valid.

However notice your debug screenshot, you are executing a piece of lua with nodejs, Look at the cli

```
C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node.exe RPSbot.lua
                        ^          ^
                        |          |
                     Path to node  |
                                  your lua file given to the node.exe
```

Unsure if there is some other js process that you used on your tablet that ran lua via nodejs or you are trying this from js yourself. But nodejs is intended for javascript files.

Using node on this piece of code produces the same error. You should run this using the lua runtime. If you haven't already, you can download lua [here](https://www.lua.org/download.html), be sure to add it to your path if needed.

Then you can run it from cli as following:

```
lua RPSbot.lua
```

Or create a batch script to call it by name without lua before it, i.e. create a file called `RPSbot.cmd` or `RPSbot.bat` and place calling code in it `lua RPSbot.lua`. The calling code might need to use the full path to lua and your script. Then you can just run that batch script each time.

If it is intended to run trough node you might need to provide more code and/or context.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!! It's my first time using VSC and I didn't know I had to manually download the runtime,,

Comment: No problem, I took a guess that you might be a bit new to something so added a few tips but tried to keep it short. Have fun programming.